# Transferring several dictionaries ApplicationContext ( from iPhone to Apple Watch )

Tags: swift, watchconnectivity

I've got a function, named didReceiveApplicationContext and I need to transfer several dictionaries there. Now, I'm using this code:

```
guard let transferData = applicationContext["dataFromAnotherDevice"] as? Int else { return }
```

When I'm trying to do the same action ( to repeat this code ), I don't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

The applicationContext API only sends delivers the most recently passed in dictionary. It sounds like you want to use transferUserInfo instead which queues up each dictionary.

Comment: Thanks you!
But, I think you didn't understood me correctly. For example , I've got several buttons on my ViewController (iPhone) and I need to send different kind of data from different buttons to Apple Watch. So, what the way to receive it?